# How to show a viedo file on html4 page

Tags: html

I have hosted video on our company server. Now, I want to show this video in an html 4 page. What should I do ? I know that in html5 it is just drag and drop but what about older version of html?

Comment: You should be aware, that since there was no video standard in HTML4, it is not possible to guarantee that this will work for browsers that are not HTML5 compliant. Your best bet is to upload the videos to Youtube and hope that they will be converted into a watchable format. I think the site does allow you to privately share your videos among users, if that's a concern.

Answer (score 0):

Playing videos in HTML is not easy!

You must add a lot of tricks to make sure your video will play in all browsers (Internet Explorer, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera) and on all hardware (PC, Mac , iPad, iPhone).

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
  <object data="movie.mp4" width="320" height="240">
    <embed src="movie.swf" width="320" height="240">
  </object> 
</video>
```

or

The  tag defines a container for external (non-HTML) content.

```
<embed src="intro.swf" height="200" width="200">
```

The  tag tag can also define a container for external (non-HTML) content.

```
<object data="intro.swf" height="200" width="200"></object>
```

**Reference:**

- http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_videos.asp